# For each prime $p$ let $S_p=\{n\in \mathbb N: \text{n is a multiple of } p\}$. $\mathscr S=\{1\}\cup \{S_p|\text {p is prime}\}$.

Tags: general-topology

For each prime $p$ let $S_p=\{n\in \mathbb N:  \text{n is a multiple of } p\}$. $\mathscr S=\{1\}\cup \{S_p|\text {p is prime}\}$. Prove that $\mathscr S$ is a sub basis for a topology on $\mathbb N$. Describe the topology generated by $\mathscr S$.

Proof:

$\mathscr S$ is a sub basis for a topology on $\mathbb N$

$n\in \mathbb N$ either $n$ is prime or composite number(it has prime factors). so $n \in S_p$ for some $p$ prime.

$S_2=2\mathbb N$

$S_3=\{3,6,9,...\}$

$S_5=\{5,10,15...\}$

...

$S_p=\{p,2p,3p,...,\}$

Basis for the topology $\mathscr B=\{B\in \mathbb{N}:$ B is the intersection of finite number of members of $\mathscr S\}$. I am not able to see, How would the topology look like. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

All it takes for a collection C of subsets of S, to
be a subbase for some topology for S is $\cup$C = S.

A base for the topology given by that subbase is
{ $S_n$ : n positive square free integer }.

The topology is coarser than the set of upper sets of P(N) determined by the order a <= b when a divides b.

Comment: what do you mean by upper sets

Comment: I guess it depends on definitions.  In the definitions I've always seen, *any* subset of $P(X)$ forms a subbasis for some topology on $X$: and $X$ is considered a finite intersection of elements of $C$ via being the empty intersection.

Comment: @Mathgeek.  A is an upper set when for all x,  (if exists a in A with a <= x, then x in A).

Comment: @DanielSchepler.  {empty set} subset P(R) and {{0}} are not subbases for any topology for R unless you're will to consider the somewhat ambiguous intersection of the empty set.